Number of integer solutions modulo $n$
Given $n$ and $k$ I would like to show that the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+\dots + x_k = r \pmod{n}$$
where the $x_i$'s are integers satisfying $0<x_i<n$ is equal for all values of $r\in \{1,2,\dots, n-1\}$. For context, this was part of an online assessment test from a company for a software engineering position. During the test, I managed to calculate the number of solutions for $r=0$ by using a roots of unity filter and guesstimated that for all other $r$ it must be equal. Then since the sum over $r$ of the number of solutions is equal to $(n-1)^k$ I managed to get the answer by solving a simple equation. However, I would like to prove that my guesstimation is indeed correct. Using a roots of unity filter gives a messy calculation when $r\neq n$ which I could not easily simplify. Then I tried to find a bijection between the set of solutions for $r$ and $r'$ but again this approach was not fruitful. Any help is appreciated!
EDIT: Here is my complete thought process. Let
$$P(x) = x + x^2 + \dots + x^{n-1}$$
Let $G(x)=P(x)^k = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots$ where the coefficients of $x^m$ where $m>\deg(G)$ are zero. Then the answer for any $r>0$ is equal to $a_0 + a_r + a_{2r} + \dots$ (here $a_0 = 0$). For $r=0$ the answer is equal to $a_0+a_n+a_{2n}+\dots$. These can be calculated exactly by root of unity filters. That is, for $r>0$ we have
$$a_0+a_r+a_{2r}+\dots = \frac{1}{r}\left(G(1)+G(\omega)+\dots + G(\omega^{r-1})\right)$$
where $\omega$ is an $r$-th root of unity. For $r=0$ we take $r=n$ in the above formula which simplifies nicely to
$$\frac{1}{n}\left((n-1)^k - (-1)^k\right)$$
Now if $r\neq n$ there is no obvious simplification.

How large is $n$?

I would think that inclusion-exclusion can be used to easily reduce the "excluding zeros" question to different sizes of the "zeros included" problem.

@Erik Wong Well you're right I think but I'm looking for a more direct approach (ideally I would like to construct a bijection)

Note: Your approach is doomed because it is not true. EG For $n = 4, k = 2$, when $ r= 0$ we have 3 solutions $(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)$. But when $ r=1$ we only have 2 solutions $(2, 3), (3, 2)$.

Note that the statement "Then the answer for any $r>0$ is equal to $a_0 + a_r + a_{2r} + \dots$ (here $a_0 = 0$)." is not true. The true version is $ a_r + a_{n+r} + a_{n+2r} + \ldots$, for which you can use the appropriate roots of unity filter (I don't know if you're aware of how to do this. The approach is reasonably direct from here.)

We establish the result via fixing the various errors in OP's roots of unity filter argument. See this writeup for the more general version, which allows for $r \neq 0$.
Let $P(x) = x + x^2 + \dots + x^{n-1} $.
Let $ \omega$ be a primitive n-th root of unity.
Show that $P(1) = n-1$, $P(\omega^r) = - 1$ for $ r \neq n$ (or a multiple of $n$).
Let $G(x)=P(x)^k = a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots$.
Let $G_r =  \sum a_{in + r} $.
We want to show that $G_r$ is constant for $r \neq 0$ (or a multiple of $n$).
Applying the roots of unity filter for $r \neq 0$,
$$ \begin{array} { l l } G_r & = \frac{   \omega^{-r} G(\omega) + \omega^{-2r} G(\omega^2) + \ldots  \omega^{-(n-1)r} G(\omega^{n-1}) +  \omega^{-nr}G(1) } { n } \\
& = \frac{(\omega^{-r} + \omega^{-2r} + \ldots + \omega^{-(n-1)r} )(-1)^k + G(1) } { n }      \\
& = \frac{ (-1) ( -1)^k + (n-1)^k } { n} \end{array} $$
Since this is independent of $r$, hence it is a constant (subject to $r \neq 0$).
In particular, for Mike's case where $n=4,k=3$, we have $G_r = \frac{1 + 3^3 } { 4 } = 7$, which agrees with his total count.
Bonus: Applying the roots of unity filter for $r=  0$,
$$ \begin{array} { l l } G_0 & = \frac{    G(\omega) + G(\omega) + \ldots + G(1) } { n } \\
& = \frac{(n-1 )(-1)^k + G(1) } { n }      \\
& = \frac{ (n-1) ( -1)^k + (n-1)^k } { n} \end{array} $$
Hence , $G_0 = G_1 + (-1)^k$.
In particular, they are never equal.
Note: If we simply assumed the result, then since $ (n-1)^k = G_0 + (n-1) G_1$ and $ n\not \mid (n-1)^k$ , hence we could have concluded that $ G_ 0 \neq G_1$.

That's exactly what I had in mind but I messed up what I wanted to calculate! Thanks for the answer.

I believe this answer is much simpler than all the others.
Let $f(n,k,r)$ be the number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=r\mod n$. We prove by induction that $f(n,k,r)$ is the same for all $r\neq 0$.
Basis: we have $f(n,1,r)=1$ if $r\neq 0$ and $f(n,1,0)=0$.
For $k\geq 2$, suppose $r\neq 0$. Consider a solution $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_k$. If the first $k-1$ terms sum to $0$, then $x_k=r$. If the first $k-1$ terms sum to $r$, then there is no solution. In all other $n-2$ cases, there is one option for $x_k$. Since $f(n,k-1,r)$ is equal to $f(n,k-1,1)$ for all $r\neq 0$ by hypothesis, we have $f(n,k,r)=f(n,k-1,0)+(n-2)f(n,k-1,1)$. This, does not depend on $r$ so we completed the induction step. This concludes the proof.
Note: this gives us the recursive relations to compute the function:
$$
f(n,k,1)=f(n,k-1,0)+(n-2)f(n,k-1,1)\\
f(n,k,0)=(n-1)f(n,k-1,1)
$$
This yields $f(n,k,1)=\frac{1}{n}(n-1)^k-\frac{(-1)^k}{n}$.

Very nice. I also came up with that approach, motivated by the counting the solutions through linear recurrence. As I've seen this problem before, I chose to focus on OP's approaches (bijection and roots of unity filter).

Very nice answer! I am marking the one that uses the roots of unity filter as accepted because this is what I had in mind initially.

You say that ideally you want to construct a bijection, so that is what I will do. Letting $X(n,k,r)$ be the set of solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_k\equiv r\pmod n$ where all variables are nonzero, I will give a bijection between $X(n,k,r)$ and $X(n,k,r')$ whenever $r,r'\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$.
Consider the correspondence mapping the vector $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)$ to its list of $k+1$ partial sums modulo $n$, where we include the empty partial sum at the beginning.
$$
\begin{align}
(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)&\mapsto (s_0,s_1,s_2,\dots,s_k),\text{ where}
\\
s_0&=0,
\\
s_i&\equiv x_1+\dots+x_i\pmod n\quad (1\le i\le k)
\end{align}
$$
Let $S(n,k,r)$ denote the image of $X(n,k,r)$ under this correspondence. Even though the bijection between $X(n,k,r)$ and $X(n,k,r')$ is hard to find, the bijection between $S(n,k,r)$ and $S(n,k,r')$ is simple to describe. Note that $S(n,k,r)$ consists of sequences of length $k+1$, starting with zero, where each pair of adjacent entries has two different numbers, and such that the last entry is $r$.

Given $(s_0,s_1,\dots,s_k)\in S(n,k,r)$, let $z$ be the greatest index for which $s_z=0$. We will modify only the entries $s_{z+1},\dots,s_{k}$ of the input, which are all nonzero. Follow these steps:

Let $t_j=s_j-1$, for each $j\in \{z+1,\dots,k\}$. Interpret $t_j$ as an element of $\mathbb Z/(n-1)\mathbb Z$.
Let $t'_j=t_j+(r'-r)\pmod{n-1}$, for each $j\in \{z+1,\dots,k\}$,
Finally, interpret $t_j'$ as an integer, and let $s_j'=t_j'+1$.

Then the vector $(s_0,\dots,s_z,s_{z+1}',\dots,s_k')$ is in $S(n,k,r')$.

Here is an example of the bijection in the case where $n=4,k=3$, $r=1$ and $r'=2$.
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
X(4,3,1) & S(4,3,1) & \text{Result of bijection}\in S(4,3,2) & X(4,3,2)
\\\hline
(1,1,3) & (0,1,2,1) & (0,\color{blue}{2,3,2}) & (2,1,3)
\\(1,2,2) & (0,1,3,1) & (0,\color{blue}{2,1,2}) & (2,3,1)
\\(1,3,1) & (0,1,0,1) & (0,1,0,\color{blue}2) & (1,3,2)
\\(2,1,2) & (0,2,3,1) & (0,\color{blue}{3,1,2}) & (3,2,1)
\\(2,2,1) & (0,2,0,1) & (0,2,0,\color{blue}{2}) & (2,2,2)
\\(3,1,1) & (0,3,0,1) & (0,3,0,\color{blue}{2}) & (3,1,2)
\\(3,3,3) & (0,3,2,1) & (0,\color{blue}{1,3,2}) & (1,2,3)
\end{array}
$$

1/ Pointing out that we require $ z < k$ which is why the argument doesn't work for $r = 0 $ (and it shouldn't). $\quad$ 2/ Your map of $s_j \rightarrow s_j'$ is better (more simply) described as conditioning on $s_j \neq n-1$.

First, we establish the result by induction.
Note that we do require $ r, r' \neq 0$, esp since otherwise the statement might not be true like I pointed out in the comments.
Clearly the base case of $k = 1$ is true, since there's exactly 1 way to write it.
Now, we want to show that the number of ways to write $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots x_{k+1} \equiv r$ is the same as the number of ways to write $x_1' + x_2' + \ldots x_{k+1}' \equiv r'$. Condition on $x_{1}$.

If $x_{1} \not \equiv r - r'$, then we map $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_k ) = (x_1 + (r'-r), x_2, \ldots x_k)$.

Note that we do not map to $x_1' = r'-r$
This is a bijection between these cases, so the number of solutions is the same.


If $x_{1} = r - r'$, then set $x_1' = r'-r$ (which we didn't map to above).

Via the induction hypothesis, the number of solutions to $x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k \equiv r - (r-r') ) \equiv r' $  is the same as the number of solutions to $x_2^* + x_3^* + \ldots + x_k ^* \equiv r' - (r'-r) \equiv r $.



Hence the number of solutions is the same, and we are done.

Second, we completely describe the bijection, by considering what happens in the induced bijection.

If $x_{1} \neq r - r'$: then $x_1' = x_1 + r'-r$ and the rest stay the same.
If $x_1 = r-r', x_2 \neq r'-r$: then $x_1' = r'-r, x_2' = x_2 + r - r'$ and the rest stay the same.
If $x_1 = r-r', x_2 = r'-r, x_3 \neq r-r'$: then $x_1' = r'-r, x_2' = r-r', x_3' = x_3 + r'-r$ and the rest stay the same.
Continue through the end.

Here is an example of the bijection using Mike's case where $n=4,k=3$, $r=1$ and $r'=2$.
$$
\begin{array}{c l l }
X(4,3,1)  & X(4,3,2) & 
\\\hline
(1,1,3) & (2,1,3) & \text{Add 1 to the 1st term}
\\(1,2,2) & (2,2,2) & \text{Add 1 to the 1st term}
\\(1,3,1) & (2,3,1) & \text{Add 1 to the 1st term}
\\(2,1,2) & (3,1,2) & \text{Add 1 to the 1st term}
\\(2,2,1) & (3,2,1) & \text{Add 1 to the 1st term}
\\ (3,1,1) &  (1,3,2) & \text{Set $x_1' = 1, x_2' = 3$, Add 1 to the 3rd term} 
\\  (3,3,3) & (1,2,3) & \text{Set $x_1' = 1$, subtract 1 from the 2nd term}\\
\end{array}
$$

$x_1, \dots, x_{k-1}$ can be anything, then simply set $x_k$ to the value to bring the sum to $r$ modulo $n$. The logic applies whether $r$ is zero or any other number. Therefore the number of solutions is the same regardless of $r$, so long as $0 \le r < n$ of course.
EDIT: This assumed $0 \le x_i < n$ instead of $0 < x_i < n$, nevermind this answer.

I'm not sure I follow the logic. How does this prove that the number of solutions is the same (including $r=0$)? Actually, the number of solutions I got for $r=0$ is different from the rest.

The proof shows the count is $n^{k-1}$, regardless of $r$, no?

well okay, didn't realize you excluded zero, well that changes things, my bad. I thought it was $0 \le x_i < n$, nevermind my answer.
